# Cut text from mysql json data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have some colums `id`, `name`, `place` and `wish`

How can I cut text in wish

```
 <?php            
    //connect to database
    include 'db.php';

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost",$db_user,$db_pass);
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
    mysql_query("set names utf8");

    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishes");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows); ?>
```

Comment: Please add to your question the output of $rows. Use var_dump($rows) to do that!

Comment: its work but not correctly $sth = mysql_query("SELECT  SUBSTR(wish, 1, 20) FROM wishes");

Comment: i have {"SUBSTR(wish, 1, 20)":"Almost all of m"}, but need {"wish":"Almost all of m"},

Answer (score 0):

My solution , work fine.

```
<?php

//connect to database
include 'db.php';

$link = mysql_connect("localhost",$db_user,$db_pass);
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
mysql_query("set names utf8");

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, place, IF(SUBSTR(wish, 1, 120)=wish, wish, CONCAT(SUBSTR(wish, 1, 120), '...')) wish FROM wishes");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;

}

print json_encode($rows);
?>
```